# Unity: Finding out where OnSelect comes from

Tags: unity, mouse, keyboard

The new UI EventSystem method OnSelect is called from a number of different sources. One is when the Selectable is selected by using the arrow keys to navigate. Another is when clicking on the Selectable.

Both these methods trigger an OnSelect on the object, but how can I find out where the selection came from, if I want to treat it differently? Any ideas?

Comment: How soon is OnSelect called once a new Object is selected? Have you tried using Input.GetMouseDown/Input.GetKeyDown or Input.GetKey to see if the Input has been recorded yet?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that after posting the question. This works, but it's a bit of an ugly solution, I feel.

Comment: Yes, it seems like the InputModule should be recording where the Input came from. Maybe I just missed it in the Docs.

Comment: Well, I've been looking for it too and couldn't find anything.

The issue also remains, that this only checks for mouse, not for touch input.